# values stored as lists inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I need some help with below question.

Print the marks which are higher than 75 (>75) with the subject code ("S1" or "S2"). Dictionary (d) is as follows.

```
d = {"S1":[80, 87, 71, 95, 78, 65], "S2": [51, 78, 65, 78, 85, 78]}
```

I have tried this.

```
d = {"CS":[80, 87, 71, 95, 78, 65], "STAT": [51, 78, 65, 78, 85, 78]}
{k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if v > 75}
```

But it gives a TYPE ERROR.

I guess my loop does not run through each value inside the lists.

Please help!

Comment: `v` is a list. You cannot compare a list and a number.

Comment: You should write nested comprehensions, one for the dictionary and another one for the list of marks.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because v is list not integer. To print all print that higher than 75 you could using filter on v

```
{k:list(filter(lambda x: x > 75, v)) for (k,v) in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `list-comprehension` for filtering out the wanted values in `v`.

```
{k: [val for val in v if val > 75] for k,v in d.items()}

{'S1': [80, 87, 95, 78], 'S2': [78, 78, 85, 78]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun way to do it using `itertools`

```
d = {"S1":[80, 87, 71, 95, 78, 65], "S2": [51, 78, 65, 78, 85, 78]}

print([value for value in list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.values())) if value > 75])
```